# Drawing a custom view in an ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-canvas, android-adapter

I am currently trying to draw an item on the left on my array adapter but for some reason, it seems to appear for only a few frames before disappearing.

Here's the code for...

**ArrowView**

```
public class ArrowView extends View {
    private Path path;
    private Paint paint;

    private void init() {
        path = new Path();
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.white));
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }

    public ArrowView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
        path.moveTo(0, 0);
        path.lineTo(0, getHeight());
        path.lineTo(getWidth(), getHeight() / 2);
        path.lineTo(0, 0);
        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        Log.d("arroview", "onDraw called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

My **fragment**:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_first_use_get_started, container, false);

    Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.leave_first_time_screen_button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });

    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.get_started_list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), R.layout.adapter_get_started, R.id.get_start_description_text_view, functionalityStrings));
    listView.setDividerHeight(0);
    listView.setEnabled(false);

    return rootView;
}
```

And finally, my adapter layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.example.ArrowView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/get_start_description_text_view"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The onDraw is called only once, and a few times during my tests the triangle were rendered somehow (can't reproduce...). I suspect it has to dot with how the ArrayAdapter works ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
this.setWillNotDraw(false);´
```

in constructor